# how to return data from arr

Tags: javascript

I need to get the results back from the array. and that is my priority for now
I need to get the results back from the array. and that is my priority for now

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` doesn't return a value it modifies the existing array. If you want to return a value you can use javascript  `Array.map()` function

```
let x = [[{lat:"32",lng:"22"},{lat:"12",lng:"43"}],[{lat:"322",lng:"252"},{lat:"612",lng:"43"}]]; 

let res= x.flatMap(y => { return y.map(z => [z.lat, z.lng] ); }); 

console.log(res);
```

Please check if this is how you meant the output to be?

Comment: How I can nested two map inside another same as forEach here ?

Comment: so what is the output you are expecting? can you please share that

Comment: I expect to return values like in last forEach  [z.lat(), z.lng()] .. z.lat is latitude , z.lng is longitude. I expect [12.312312 , 43.342432] , [15.313412 , 34.342432] ,  [12.313412 , 22.342432] ...

Comment: let x = [[{lat:"32",lng:"22"},{lat:"12",lng:"43"}],[{lat:"322",lng:"252"},{lat:"612",lng:"43"}]]; 
let res= x.map(y => { 
            return y.map(z => [z.lat, z.lng]  );
        });
console.log(res);
Please check if this is how you meant the out put to be?

Comment: This is no good result.. I have one more array inside. instead [12.312312 , 43.342432] , [15.313412 , 34.342432] , [12.313412 , 22.342432]  i have 

[[12.312312 , 43.342432]] , [[15.313412 , 34.342432]] , [[12.313412 , 22.342432]]

Comment: Ok I have updated the answer check it

Answer (score 0):

forEach() — executes a provided function once for each array element.
so the the forEach() method doesn’t actually return anything (undefined).

You can use map instead. map creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

credit to the article: https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f